# How to remove existing migration and add from scratch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have just created a migration with this following Model and updated the database and the table is created

```
public class ZipSearchHistory: BaseEntity
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I realized that there will be int instead of string in ZipCode. So I deleted all the migrations file and also deleted the table in SSMS manually in order to start from scratch. Now I applied Migration.

My migration code is :

```
public partial class ZipCodeSearchHistoryTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.ZipSearchHistories", "ZipCode", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        DropColumn("dbo.ZipSearchHistories", "Zip");
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.ZipSearchHistories", "Zip", c => c.String());
        DropColumn("dbo.ZipSearchHistories", "ZipCode");
    }
}
```

and when I try op update-database I get an error

> Cannot find the object "dbo.ZipSearchHistories" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can try deleting the Migrations data in your database. Also, when you make any change in your class, you don't have to restart all over again. Just `add-migration Change2` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted migration files apart from that if you are starting like from *scratch* again I would say **delete the dbcontext snapshot file as well** because it seems you haven't.

Because right now what currently has happened is Entity framework compared the changes with the snapshot file. (That is the reason you only see changes being done for `zipcode` column and don't see it creating a fresh new table again as you would be expecting I guess as you deleted the data from migrations table in db)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations?view=aspnetcore-3.1